# Optimal linking in synchronous environment for shortest path tree problem

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, distributed-systems, synchronization

I am dealing with the Shortest path tree problem in the specific synchronous environment.

In the following algorithm, initiator begin the execution calling primitives `Construct`. This primitive  offers every neighbors but its father to be linked to the tree by a construction message `cons`.

```
Construct()
    Begin
        For all j in neighbor_i\{father_i}
        send_to(j,cons,distance+1));
    End For
End
```

Receiving a message, the site looks if the distance is the best put forward is better than the current distance. If it is the case, then it accepts the proposition and calls itself `Construct` to offer to its neighbors to become their father because it got closer to the root.

**In a synchronous environment, the algorithm is the same but we have to notify that as far as the environment is synchronous, the first linking proposition is unavoidably the best**.

1. I don't understand this assumption.
2. We notice that root is linked to pulse $0$, but I don't understand
       why sites at the distance $i$ are linked to pulse $i$.

Ask me if you need some more details.